# How to do proper case folding with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec, attoparsec

Is there a way to do proper case folding with `Parsec` (say I want a parser that behaves like `stringCI` from [`Data.Attoparsec.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.1.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v%3astringCI)).
The code that does case insensitive parsing in [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) just uses `char (toLower c) <|> char (toUpper c)`, but no proper case folding. So I'm puzzled whether this is possible at all.

Comment: For the dumb among us, can you say what's wrong with `char (toLower c) <|> char (toUpper c)`?

Comment: I'd not say that it is wrong, it is just different from case folding.  The following property does not hold `prop_foo s = length s == (length . foldCase) s`. Say case folding may change the length of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsec doesn't have any functionality for this built-in, but you could implement it with e.g. [`foldCase`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/case-insensitive/latest/doc/html/Data-CaseInsensitive.html#v%3afoldCase) from the [case-insensitive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive) package and [`satisfy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v%3asatisfy) in a loop. I'm not a Unicode expert, so I'm not sure what extra precautions you'd have to take to ensure correctness.

The [text-icu](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu) package is recommended in the documentation of `foldCase` if you need locale-sensitive conversions; it seems to be pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I still see no easy way to do it. `satisfy` works on one character at a time, while `foldCase` works on a sequence of characters. Of course I could case fold the argument to my parser (lets call it `stringCI`, like it is called in attoparsec), but how would I transform (case fold) the input stream?

Comment: @user1078763: Hmm, I suppose it's not quite so simple since it's not a character-by-character transformation... If your string has a known ending (e.g. whitespace), you could read up until that ending point and then check it for correctness. Alternatively, you could try case-folding one-element strings consisting of each character `satisfy` gives you; that would fail for context-dependent foldings, though, like Greek sigma.

Comment: I mean there is one ugly solution that I can imagine: Repeatedly `try anyChar` and case fold everything you got so far until it either (a) matches the case folded argument to `stringCI` or (b) is longer than the case folded argument to `stringCI`. Then succeed on (a) and fail on (b).

Comment: @user1078763: Yes, that's probably the best you'll get. You could optimise it by assuming that, e.g., if you read four characters and the first case-folded character doesn't match the first character of the string, then it'll never match. But I don't know how non-local the effects of case folding can be.